# "insert" menu item not displaying in tinymce

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using the last version (4.1), just trying a basic example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><!-- CDN hosted by Cachefly -->
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
        tinymce.init(
        {
        selector:'textarea',
        menu : { // this is the complete default configuration
            file   : {title : 'File'  , items : 'newdocument'},
            edit   : {title : 'Edit'  , items : 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall'},
            insert : {title : 'Insert', items : 'link media | template hr'},
            view   : {title : 'View'  , items : 'visualaid'},
            format : {title : 'Format', items : 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat'},
            table  : {title : 'Table' , items : 'inserttable tableprops deletetable | cell row column'},
            tools  : {title : 'Tools' , items : 'spellchecker code'}
        }
        }

        );
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <textarea>Your content here.</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason the "insert" menu doesn't show up in the menu bar. I have also tried downloading the full package with all the plugins, same results both in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I needed to add the plugin line to the configuration, something like

```
plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
```